# Apply styles to element but not elements inside another element

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have a code something like

```
<input type='text' />
<br />
<iframe>
    <input type='text'>
</iframe>
```

and a style

```
input[type='text'] {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

and I wanted the styles to be applied only to elements outside the iframe. How would I be able to achieve it? I was actually looking at the css `:not` selector but I am confused on how I should use it. I'd like to achieve something like

```
input[type='text'], input:not(iframe) {
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

or *Apply styles to all input of type text BUT NOT to input of type text inside an iframe*.

Comment: Styles from your main page by default doesn't apply to elements from the iframe. Can you explain more precisely what would you like to achieve?

Comment: for some reason, the external styles defined is being applied to the ones inside the iframe. I'd like these styles not to be applied inside an iframe. I'm using materializeCSS framework btw.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to select elements outside some element with CSS.

You have to create a class with the desired style definition and apply it to all inputs individually.

The `:not` selector can be used to select ALL elements but the one specified as argument e.g: `:not(p)` will select all element from the page except paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

input[type="text"]{border: 1px solid #000}

iframe input[type="text"]{border: none}

Comment: I've actually thought of this but I'm looking for an easier approach on how I could use the same styles but adding only 1 line just to include which elements I don't want the style to be applied. I'm actually using a design framework (much like bootstrap) so I wanted to stop the default behavior of some elements inside the iframe having the same styles as the ones outside the iframe.

Comment: :not is allowed only for same labeled child elements. but here iframe is not a child among inputs.

Answer (score 0):

It should work as listed. Iframes are isolated and should have their own styles, are you including the same style-sheet on both pages?